# C# passing this as container reference to class constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, containers

I want to perform

```
this.Controls.Add(MyObject)
```

in the class definition of MyObject like

```
public MyClass(container/*?*/ con,Point L)
{
con.Controls.Add(this);
}
```

can I do something like this?
thanks.

Comment: Is this for winforms/wpf/silverlight/asp/none of the above?

Comment: this is for a windows forms application in c#. I want to create "checkpoints" with certain images (pictureboxes)

Comment: What is MyClass? Derived from ... ?

Comment: It is "CheckPoint.cs" which I defined, it has a picturebox and some methods to create and move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control` will work just fine.

```
public void method(Control container)
{
    container.Controls.Add(this);
}
```

If you pass in a `Control` that can't actually have children (say, `TextBox`) it will either do nothing or throw an exception at runtime.